# Linking HABTM Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm currently trying to create a link to a new page which displays all the posts that belong to a certain category. They're both connected via a HABTM relationship as you can see below.

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= post.categories.collect(&:name).join(",") %>
```

How would I go about creating a link from a posts category attribute to a page which displays all posts from that certain category?

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% post.categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to post.title, post_url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Change `post.title` and `post_url` appropriately.

Comment: But would this link to a page which lists all posts that belong to that category?

Comment: Try it out and find out for yourself :-) HABTM works both ways; `post.categories` & `category.posts` give appropriate records back.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far! Appreciated. I'm getting an exception here which states **No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]**

Comment: You need to specify the correct values for the url linking to the post. Looks like it would be `post_url(post)`

Comment: I've changed to **<%= link_to category.name, post_url(post) %>** to make it the category name, but how would I link to a page which lists the posts belonging to that category?